# Flex 3 : "&lt;1" yr from Xml list is not coming on Y Axis in bar chart

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a xml source like this

```
<TS val="2005">
<DP y="75-79 yr" l="-114.9" r="108.6" />
<DP y="&lt;1 yr" l="-13.9" r="11.8" />
<DP y="&gt;85 yr" l="-117.5" r="104.0" />
<DP y="70-74 yr" r="39.2" l="-33.1" /></TS>
```

In FlexBuilder 3:
the chart Y axis is not showing the value for `"&lt;1 yr"` where as others are coming like `"&gt;85 yr"`.

So any one say that how `&lt;` can be handled in flex 3 to display this value.

Answer (score 1):

Escape < symbol with `&lt;` or `&#60;`

Comment: this is not helpful.
I am already giving &lt; but it is not showing event after trying ##60
value. I am still getting blank Y Axis value in Flex chart control.